# Is 'GRAND TOTAL AMOUNT' verbose?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

After the subtotals and net totals, finally it comes to the *grand total*.

Should I say "the *grand total amount* is $100", or only "the *total amount* is $100", or "* grand total amount* is $100"?

Comment: See Cornbread Ninja's answer to your other question. It's just Grand Total.

Comment: You could link to the 'other question', for everyone here to know.

Comment: The 'other question': http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65410/what-can-i-title-this-column-on-an-invoice

Comment: 1. The other Q. is different. 2. Corn's answer there is incorrect. How are those helpful here?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It's just **Grand Total**, 'amount' is unnecessary.

Comment: You sure it's not 'grand amount'?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go so far as to say the `amount` in "Grand Total Amount" is *redundant*. The word `total` in this context implies there is a countable number, which is the exact thing `amount` is saying.

Comment: Incidentally, 'amount' here means 'a sum of money', not just 'any quantity'.